# Phantom Partition ... how do I correct this?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I've done a clean install twice since this appeared (not to fix this, as everything seems to be working). Gparted doesn't show any such partition. I'm about to do another clean install, so this is the time to get it right. Any advice on where to begin?

[image]

[image]

---

```
 marc@Thor:~$ blkid
 /dev/sda1: UUID="1bd1fc27-31da-4515-b1b1-2d4acea80abe" TYPE="ext4" 
 /dev/sda5: UUID="e54014fa-3d67-42c0-9532-b5b5efc35e5b" TYPE="swap" 
 marc@Thor:~$
```

---

```
 marc@Thor:~$ cat /proc/partitions
 major minor  #blocks  name

    8        0  312571224 sda
    8        1  308659200 sda1
    8        2          1 sda2
    8        5    3909632 sda5
   11        0    1048575 sr0
 marc@Thor:~$
```

---

```
 marc@Thor:~$ sudo blkid -p /dev/sda2
 [sudo] password for marc: 
 /dev/sda2: PTTYPE="dos" PART_ENTRY_SCHEME="dos" PART_ENTRY_TYPE="0x5" PART_ENTRY_NUMBER="2" PART_ENTRY_OFFSET="617322494" PART_ENTRY_SIZE="7819266" PART_ENTRY_DISK="8:0" 
 marc@Thor:~$`
```

Comment: Is there a corrupted CD in the the drive?

Comment: Can gparted delete all the other partitions? I'm not sure what you mean "phantom".

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/recovering-ext4-superblocks

Comment: Carl H - No, nothing in the CD, no USB drive plugged in. It's just always there.

Comment: Tim - When I do a clean install, I delete all partitions and create separate partitions for `/boot`, `/`, and `swap`. As for "phantom", it won't mount and gparted can't see it.

Comment: Your sda2 is an extended partition. You cannot write or use it directly. It is more like a container for all the logical partitions you have. And you can have an unlimited number of logical partitions, but currently only have swap in the extended as a logical. So extended and one logical are the same size.

Comment: @oldfred - I don't see how that relates to the `Debian wheezy` entry. I did try Debian, and this problem began after I replaced it with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Add the output of `blkid` to your question

Comment: just to make sure, how about `cat /proc/partitions` and `sudo blkid -p /dev/sda2`.

Comment: Yep.. there really can't be anything in that partition that could identify it as an iso9660 fs.. something has really gone wrong with udisks.  File a bug against the udisks2 package and include the output of `udisksctl dump`.

Comment: Before trying to re-install, try creating a new partition table and report back...  (I thing you've got a corrupted one)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you had a Debian image on your hard disk (either in a file or written "raw" to a partition) and that it just happens to have been stored where your `/dev/sda2` now begins. Because `/dev/sda2` is basically just a placeholder for your `/dev/sda5`, which is swap space, it could be that enough of the original disc image remains on the disk to confuse the auto-mounter.

If I'm right, the fix is to overwrite whatever data the auto-mounter is seeing that's making it think the Debian image is on `/dev/sda2`. The trouble with this solution is that anything you might do is potentially risky; you might accidentally trash some or all of your data. Thus, if you intend to follow my suggestions, you must *do so at your own risk,* and I ***STRONGLY*** advise you to ***back up your important user data first!***

Those caveats out of the way, the simplest and easiest thing to do is to ensure that `/dev/sda2`'s first sector is clear of unnecessary data:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2 bs=440 count=1
```

Type this command *exactly* as shown here. A mistake with any of the options could result in serious data loss. After you type this command, reboot and see if things have improved. If they haven't, you could try a longer and riskier procedure:

1. In a Terminal window, type `sudo swapoff` to disable your use of swap space.
2. Using GParted, `parted`, or `fdisk`, delete `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda2`.
3. Create a new `/dev/sda2`, but make it a regular primary partition, not an extended partition. If you use `fdisk`, give it a type code of 0x82 (Linux swap). If you use `parted`, give it a "file system type" of `linux-swap`.
4. Reboot. This ensures that you'll be using the new partition table.
5. Type `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2`. Be ***extra extra super*** careful with this command. Pay particular attention to the `of=` value -- it should be `/dev/sda2`, ***not*** `/dev/sda` or any other value. The point of this command is to completely erase the disk space occupied by `/dev/sda2`. If you accidentally specify the wrong target, you'll wipe out whatever it holds.
6. Create new swap space on `/dev/sda2`.

   - If you used `fdisk` or `parted` for partitioning, type `sudo mkswap /dev/sda2`. Again, be very careful with the disk device.
   - If you used GParted for partitioning, it's easiest to go back in to GParted to set `/dev/sda2` up as swap space.
7. Type `sudo blkid /dev/sda2`. This will show you the UUID value associated with the swap space.
8. Edit `/etc/fstab` and change the UUID value associated with swap from the old value to the new one.
9. Reboot and test. The problem should be gone.

As you can see by all the caveats and warnings, this procedure is far from risk-free. I recommend you try it only if you're already familiar with low-level tools like `dd` and `fdisk`.

It's conceivable that a tiny resize operation on your partition will clear up the problem; for instance, you could shrink `/dev/sda1` by 1MiB and resize `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda5` to fill that space. I can't promise this would work, though; it's conceivable that the move/resize will move the errant disc image data along with everything else.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but since this is an extended partition, it only exposes two sectors, and one of them is the EBR.  The identification that this is an iso9660 filesysem is at like sector 32 or something, certainly not in the second sector, so that doesn't make sense.  If you want to make sure then you can just zero that second sector as is without having to delete and recreate any partitions.

Comment: The extended partition covers a much wider range than just two sectors. In many cases, the first logical partition begins 2048 sectors after the first sector of the extended partition, so there are plenty of sectors in there that have probably not been erased. It's entirely possible for a Linux program to access any sector it wants (if it's got root access). I know this because my own GPT fdisk tools do so in order to read the extended partition data structures. Thus, it's plausible that the automounter got confused by old data.

Comment: I backup regularly anyway, so the risk is minimal. I'll give this a try when I have a few consecutive hours to dedicate to extreme caution and a complete re-install and restore if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Not in linux... it always exposes an extended partition as having only two sectors, regardless of how many lie between the EBR and the logical partition ( though that *almost* always is only 2 ).  The fact that it is exposed this way, and indeed at all, is a hack that dates back to LILO: exposing the first two sectors allowed LILO to be installed there and chain loaded by DOS MBR boot code.

Comment: It depends on how it's being accessed. Trust me; I wrote the GPT fdisk code, which reads and parses MBR data structures, and it *is* possible to access any sector within an extended partition if you care to do so.

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up to be creating a new partition table as part of a re-install. I nuked it from orbit.